# Can elements from a native iPhone app and jqTouch web app interact?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, jqtouch

I have a native iPhone app loading a cached jQTouch web app inside UIWebView. How can elements within the jQTouch app seamlessly link to elements and actions in the native app (if at all)?

When loading a web app page, a link when pressed, sends an id to the native app.

Comment: Did you understand my answer ?

Comment: @F.Santoni yes, sorry I up voted but was waiting on other potential answers/solutions to see if other solutions may have worked better but your answer makes sense and is what I would have expected, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes !

The best way to do a such thing is to implement a UIWebView delegate.

Then you choose an event url scheme (like http://id:123/click/ )

And just parse the URL in this method :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

You can check the URL value with :

```
[request.URL absoluteString]
```